Change the icon of BackButon() in my appbar
I have a BackButon() in my appbar , I want to change the default icon of BackButton in FLUTTER.
here is the appBar code:
appBar: AppBar(
        leading: BackButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Get.off(exercisePage());
          },
        ),

        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
        ),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
          child: Text(
            'Regular exercise',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'FontMain', fontSize: 22, color: Colors.indigo),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 235, 237),
       
      ),


There is no direct way to change icons in BackButton.
To change the icon, you need to add a custom IconButton Widget To Leading, and give up on tap for function, or use GestureDetector or InkWell Widget.

    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, //change the icon here
 color: Colors.black),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      ), 
      title: Text("Sample"),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),


   appBar: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back, // This is icon for change for your side
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      centerTitle: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0,
      title: const Text(
        "Testing",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 22,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
      ),
    ),

